# Is it usual for Scikit learn's standard scaler to cause non-invertibility?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, normal-equation

For example, I am trying to perform linear regression on the following set of data

Data examples:
$X = [[1, 20], [3, 40], [5, 60]]$ (each row is an example, there are three examples, each with a feature of $2$, arranged in Numpy array)

Targets:
$y = [1, 2, 3]$ (whatever you like, it doesn't affect our result.

Fitting a standardscaler gives me,

```
X = [[1, 20], [3, 40], [5, 60]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
Y = scaler.transform(X)
```

$Y = [[-1.22474487 -1.22474487]
 [ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.22474487  1.22474487]]$

Now I want to compute the normal equation of a linear regression problem. This inolves calculating the following matrix $Z = (Y^T Y)^{-1} Y^T$

```
Z = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(Y), Y))*np.transpose(Y)
```

I get LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Note that this does not seem to be a problem with the original data set $X$

Is this a usual behavior or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Since you have two features, YtY should be a 2×2 matrix and not 3×3 matrix. Try (YYt)inv Y instead.

Answer (score 0):

A linear or affine (with fixed constant term) transformation like scaling should **not change the rank of a matrix nor its invertibility**. This is one point. However according to [documentation of StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), `StandardScaler` scales each feature independantly (ie. no longer a uniform linear/affine transformation, constant terms are multiple), so this **can in fact alter the rank and invertibility of a matrix of data** (for example use a different scaler).

A further point is that the formula for Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse you use is [valid only in certain cases (ie. for linearly independent columns)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linearly_independent_columns) else a more general formula should be used. Check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root confusion is the nuance between linear and affine relationships, which is not something that becomes a problem in most of data science (we generally allow affine relationships even if we use the word "linear").

The matrix $X$ has full rank: the columns demonstrate an affine relationship ($x_2=10x_1+10$), but not a linear one.  So $X^T X$ (which is $2\times2$) is indeed invertible, and everything proceeds normally.

If you add an all-ones column to $X$ (to incorporate an intercept to the OLS), you elevate the affine relationship to a linear one, and you'll find that $X^T X$ is not invertible.

The `StandardScaler` (in addition to scaling) centers the features, which again rips away the bias/shift, and turns the affine relationship to a linear one (of course, it's the identity relationship).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your example data in the first place (not related to scaling). It produces a prefect fit. This will also translate to scaled data. You also need to add an constant term in order to solve $(X'X)^{-1} X'y = \hat{\beta}$.

**Example in R:**

df = data.frame(y=c(1,2,3),x1=c(1,3,5),x2=c(20,40,60))
summary(lm(y~x1+x2,data=df))

> Warning message: In summary.lm(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)) :
> essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

```
x0 <- c(1,1,1) 
x1 <- c(1,3,5)
x2 <- c(20,40,60)
x <- as.matrix(cbind(x0,x1,x2))
y <- as.matrix(c(1,2,3))

# (X'X)^-1 X'y
beta1 = solve(t(x)%*%x) %*% t(x)%*%y
```

> Error in solve.default(t(x) %*% x) :    Lapack routine dgesv: system
> is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0